# Display 7 dates of current week in earlier Android

Tags: java, android, datetime

I'm using the *java.time* package of java to display week dates based on the current date in Android. I want Sunday through Saturday.

But the 'Time package [link:](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary?hl=EN) ' was added from API 26. So, it is not supported for below API 26. So, I need an alternate solution for this. So that, I can run in below API 26.

Please provide me an alternate solution to display week dates based on the current date in Android.

Comment: Do you want dates of past 7 days (If today is Wednesday then last Thursday to today) or this Sunday to upcoming Saturday even if today is Tuesday.

Comment: Sunday to upcoming Saturday

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). *ThreeTenABP* is the backport of java.time to earlier Android (before API level 26).

Comment: Post your clarifications as edits to the Question, not Comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, it is not supported for below API 26.

You *can* use the *java.time* functionality in earlier Android. Use the back-port.

> So, I need an alternate solution for this.

No, you don’t.

Keep your code as-is. The back-port carries nearly the same API. So you’ll need do little more than swap your *import* statements.

## ThreeTen-Backport

Most of the *java.time* functionality is  back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the *[ThreeTen-Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)* project.

This project is led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne, who leads the JSR 310 spec, the *java.time* implementation, and *Joda-Time*.

## ThreeTenABP

The *ThreeTen-Backport* project is further adapted to Android specifically in the *ThreeTenABP* project.

## Code

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Or ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;

LocalDate localDate = today.with( org.threeten.bp.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ) ;
List< LocalDate > dates = new ArrayList<>( 7 ) ;
for( int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i ++ ) {
    localDate = localDate.plusDays( i ) ;
    dates.add( localDate ) ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have implemented your code in my app but I am getting some conflicts in dates. Please check this link: https://photos.app.goo.gl/bMrupWd47QSyAidN6.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
    int NUM_DAYS = 7; // You can get as many dates as you want.

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY); // The first day you want dates from.

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());

    for (int i=0; i < NUM_DAYS; i++){ 

        Date date = calendar.getTime();

        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MM/yyyy").format(date));

        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is two Calendar objects.

```
Calendar calendarCurrent = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarCurrent.getTime(); // To get current date-time.

Calendar calendarWeek = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarWeek.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
calendarWeek.getTime(); // To get after 7 day's date-time.
```

If you want to display it in calendar-view then you can set maxDate as below.

```
calendarView.setMinDate(calendarCurrent.getTimeInMillis());
calendarView.setMaxDate(calendarWeek.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: OP isn't asking for date of next 7 days.